# Id listener issue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map api v3. There are multiple markers on the map. When someone click on infowindow then there should be alert message pop up. but it's not listening that id of content.

Here is the code:
Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#languages").click(function(){
    alert("Perfect");
  });
});
</script>
```

infowindow content:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var content="<div name='languages' value='Ronak Patel' id='languages'>RRP</div>";
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();  
    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.open(marker.get('map'), marker);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are creating the `languages` dynamically, `.click()` wont work

try this

```
$(document).on('click', '#languages', function(){
    alert("Perfect");
});
```

Read more on [event delegation using `on` here](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

if content is more then once in there, you have duplicate ID's..

try to set class="languages"
and then

```
$(".languages").click(function(){
     alert("Perfect");
});
```

or this, if you have to delegate it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.languages', function(){
    alert("Perfect");
});
```